# Restrict Account records to specific group of users

Tags: sharing

Looking for options to restrict a set of Account records(Based on Recordtype) to all users in the org and should be visible to specific set of users, with out impacting current functionalities.
Current - OWD is Private , Sharing rules allows accounts based on status & few profiles with View all access.

Any suggestions would be apricated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Sharing Rules**, which are a feature that allows you to grant additional access to records based on criteria such as record owner, role, profile, or public group.

For example, you could create a sharing rule that only allows users in a certain public group to view or edit account records that meet certain criteria, such as record type, industry, or territory.

Refer to this for more information:

- [Sharing Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_about_sharing_rules.htm&type=5)
- [Manual Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.granting_access_to_records.htm&type=5)
- [Scoping Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_scoping_rule.htm&type=5)

Comment: Restriction Rules are not supported on Account Object.